# StackApps review progress b0rken

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, review-stats

In the new reviewing queue on StackApps.com, you won't be able to see the detailed progress bars. When you hover over the single progress bar, you see:

[image: narrow progress display]

The width of the wrapping div has been constrained to 9 pixels and no background has been set. Oops?

Comment: @lockstep: 'b0rken' is a [deliberate misspelling](http://www.b0rken.net/). :-)

Comment: Sorry. I already suspected it shortly after my edit. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next deploy will include proper styling for Stack Apps.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: I'll just trust you on that and flog you (by unaccepting again) if I don't see improvement soon. :-P