# Is fun allowed on MSO?

Tags: support, questions, etiquette, fun

Currently on MSO 145 questions are tagged with [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) tag. They are very funny and I love to read them.

Many of questions are old. So currently is fun allowed on MSO?

If yes, what are etiquettes to write fun questions?

Comment: Fun was forcibly removed from power in a coup by Srs Bsns.

Comment: We [do have fun from time to time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143130/), even though that one still started out as a somewhat serious request (or bug report even) which was initially significantly downvoted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fun is certainly allowed on MSO, but only if it is in context of an on-topic, constructive question.

Basically, fun-for-fun-sake is non-constructive and off-topic.

I've been known to use humour from time to time. Really! I know, I usually sound like a serious dolt, but I have not been above tongue-in-cheek language in posts:

- [Why are the Fanatic and Enthusiast badges not earnable more than once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156495/why-are-the-fanatic-and-enthusiast-badges-not-earnable-more-than-once/156496#156496)
- [Why not make a startup stack overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145702/why-not-make-a-startup-stack-overflow/145703#145703)
- [Reputation ranking system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154777/reputation-ranking-system/154778#154778)
- [StackApps review progress b0rken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156467/stackapps-review-progress-b0rken)
- [Suggested edit actions in review queue no workie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150181/suggested-edit-actions-in-review-queue-no-workie)

Note that the above are mostly actual on-topic questions and answers, I kept the fun to side-jokes instead. Most of the fun here on MSO we keep fun to the comments.

Comment: what are etiquettes to write fun questions

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Etiquette for fun questions: Don't.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: That's fun-for-fun-sake. Don't do that.

Comment: *"I've been known to use humour from time to time"*...ha...never noticed.... ;)

Comment: @Bart: Don't make me get my slapping trout, now!

Answer (score 2):

Using humour to improve the readability of a post or to help make your point while writing a serious question or a serious answer is acceptable, and if [done well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) can be given a fair amount of latitude, but asking 'funny' questions for the sake of it is frowned upon on the main Stack Exchange sites, at least.